# Ansible roles depending on other roles not running multiple times

Tags: dependencies, ansible

I'm running Ansible 1.9.3 and have been unable to get the [role dependency wheel/tire example](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#role-dependencies) from the Ansible documentation working.

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 1.9.3
  configured module search path = None
```

Here are my files:

```
$ find ./ -type f | while read f; do printf "# %s\n" "$f"; cat "$f"; printf "\n\n"; done

# ./inventory
[webservers]
example.com

# ./roles/app/meta/main.yml
---
dependencies:
  - { role: wheel, n: 1 }
  - { role: wheel, n: 2 }
  - { role: wheel, n: 3 }
  - { role: wheel, n: 4 }

# ./roles/tire/tasks/main.yml
- name: "tire {{ n }}"
  command: "echo tire {{ n }}"

# ./roles/wheel/meta/main.yml
---
allow_duplicates: yes
dependencies:
  - { role: tire }

# ./roles/wheel/tasks/main.yml
- name: "wheel {{ n }}"
  command: "echo wheel {{ n }}"

# ./site.yml
---
- include: webservers.yml

# ./webservers.yml
---
- hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - role: app
```

So the `app` role depends on four instances of the `wheel` role, which in turn depend on the `tire` role.

However, running the playbook shows only one execution of the `tire` task:

```
$ ansible-playbook -v -i inventory site.yml

PLAY [webservers] ************************************************************* 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [example.com]

TASK: [tire | tire 1] ********************************************************* 
changed: [example.com] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["echo", "tire", "1"], "delta": "0:00:00.004721", "end": "2015-09-29 16:55:27.075745", "rc": 0, "start": "2015-09-29 16:55:27.071024", "stderr": "", "stdout": "tire 1", "warnings": []}

TASK: [wheel | wheel 1] ******************************************************* 
changed: [example.com] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["echo", "wheel", "1"], "delta": "0:00:00.004355", "end": "2015-09-29 16:55:27.806182", "rc": 0, "start": "2015-09-29 16:55:27.801827", "stderr": "", "stdout": "wheel 1", "warnings": []}

TASK: [wheel | wheel 2] ******************************************************* 
changed: [example.com] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["echo", "wheel", "2"], "delta": "0:00:00.005012", "end": "2015-09-29 16:55:28.539339", "rc": 0, "start": "2015-09-29 16:55:28.534327", "stderr": "", "stdout": "wheel 2", "warnings": []}

TASK: [wheel | wheel 3] ******************************************************* 
changed: [example.com] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["echo", "wheel", "3"], "delta": "0:00:00.003573", "end": "2015-09-29 16:55:29.259193", "rc": 0, "start": "2015-09-29 16:55:29.255620", "stderr": "", "stdout": "wheel 3", "warnings": []}

TASK: [wheel | wheel 4] ******************************************************* 
changed: [example.com] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["echo", "wheel", "4"], "delta": "0:00:00.003541", "end": "2015-09-29 16:55:29.981742", "rc": 0, "start": "2015-09-29 16:55:29.978201", "stderr": "", "stdout": "wheel 4", "warnings": []}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
example.com : ok=6    changed=5    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I've tried various combinations of `allow_duplicates: yes|no` in the two `meta/main.yml` files, but get the same result every time. The goal is to have four executions of both the `wheel` and `tire` tasks, with `n` equal to 1,2,3,4.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue and submitted a ticket to the Ansible github repo: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11205

It has been merged into v2.0.  Since 2.0 hasn't been released yet and it's unclear what migration will entail, I was forced to restructure my roles.  I believe I combined them into the same role, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I stopped using 2.0alpha due to a different bug and switched back to 1.9.3, but maybe I'll test it out again. I've more or less given up on trying to use parameterized role dependencies. Instead I'm using templates to generate static roles including all the tasks the role needs.